# Assign time stored as a string to the Value property of a DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker

I have a time value that I am reading from a db that is in military format with "." as the separating character (Format: `"HH.mm.ss"` Example: `"15.32.18"`).

What is the best way for me to display this string using a DateTimePicker.  The date time picker is formated as follows:

```
timePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
timePicker.CustomFormat = "HH.mm.ss";
```

The only way I can think of is to create a `DateTime` object with the time value that is stored in the string and assign that to my `timePicker`.  This seems to be a backwards way of doing it.

Comment: I don't think that's a backwards way of doing it - that seems correct.  What makes you think it's backwards?

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't sound backwards. A DateTimePicker inherently works with DateTime objects so you need to create a DateTime object.

Comment: It would involve parsing the string from "HH.mm.ss" to a format that the DateTime object can accepts.  As apposed to something like: timePicker.Value = Convert.ToDateTime("15.64.15", "HH.mm.ss");

Comment: @Azzi Ahh, I misinterpreted.  When you said parse I thought you meant with the `.Parse()` or `Convert.ToDateTime()` methods, not manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("15.32.18", "HH.mm.ss", null)
```

gives a date with the time portion 3:32:18 PM.